# unsupported operand type "float" and "str"

Tags: python, python-2.7, operators

i'm trying to print the operation however the first statement is working but second statement has error.

```
conSwitch = raw_input("Enter cycle of context switch: ")
cycleOpr = raw_input("Enter cycle operation: ")

totalCycle = float(conSwitch) + float(cycleOpr) + float(conSwitch)

print "Context =", conSwitch
print "Cycle operation =", cycleOpr
print "Context switch back =", conSwitch
print("\n")

print (conSwitch + " + " + cycleOpr + " + " + conSwitch)
print ("Total number of cycle is: " + format(totalCycle))
print("===================================================")

reqSecond = raw_input("Enter cycle request second:")

print "Total cycle request =", totalCycle
print "Cycle request per second =", reqSecond
print("\n")

totalSpent = float(totalCycle) * float(reqSecond)
print (totalCycle + " * " + reqSecond)
print ("Total number of spent = " + format(totalSpent))
```

==============================================================

```
First statement
Work===>> print (conSwitch + " + " + cycleOpr + " + " + conSwitch)

Second statement
Error===>> print (totalCycle + " * " + reqSecond)
```

Comment: print ("Total number of spent = {0} ".format(totalSpent)) or "Total cycle request = {0}".format(totalCycle)

Comment: I think it's because you're trying to concatenate a float with a string. Try `print (str(totalCycle) + " * " + str(reqSecond))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the variable `totalCycle` is of type **float**. Python does not know what it means to do **+** between a type **float** and **string** (because `" * "` is a **string**).

To do it the way you showed you have to convert `totalCycle` to string first, like this:

```
print (str(totalCycle) + " * " + reqSecond)
```

Answer (score 0):

[FORMAT Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

```
"First, thou shalt count to {0}"  # References first positional argument
"Bring me a {}"                   # Implicitly references the first positional argument
"From {} to {}"                   # Same as "From {0} to {1}"
"My quest is {name}"              # References keyword argument 'name'
"Weight in tons {0.weight}"       # 'weight' attribute of first positional arg
"Units destroyed: {players[0]}"   # First element of keyword argument 'players'.
```